# Can a 6 vertex graph whose complement contains 2 components with 3 vertices each ever be planar?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading this paper (*[Every Planar Graph with Nine Points Has a Nonplanar Complement](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183524923)*). As part of Proposition 1, it states that if graph $G$ has

- at least 7 vertices
- and its complement $\overline{G}$ contains 2 components
- with each component of $\overline{G}$ containing at least 3 vertices

then $G$ contains $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph.

This confused me, though. Isn't this true not just for graphs with at least 7 vertices, but also for graphs with 6 vertices? After all, if you have 3 vertices each in 2 non-connected components in the complement, wouldn't that mean that they contain a complete bipartite graph as a subgraph, and wouldn't this be $K_{3,3}$?

Apologies if this is basic, but I'm feeling confused. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that seems true, by your argument. Maybe the author of the paper considered that so trivial as to not be worthy further mentioning.

Comment: Thanks! Though if the result is trivial for at least 6 vertices it should also be trivial for 7 vertices, and they mention that...

Comment: Agreed. After some thought I realized that the argument doesn't change for more vertices. I looked at the paper and also don't see anything that you may have missed. Maybe the reason it is stated that way is that is *needed* for $n \ge 7$ only.